# Apache2 mod_proxy: backend servers log frontend server as source of all requests

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, lamp, mod-proxy

I have five servers running Ubuntu (LAMP). One of them (called Server1) receves all incomming requests from the internet, and uses VirtualHosts and mod_proxy to deliver the correct request to the correct server on the LAN.

My problem is that in all the logs on my backend servers, all requests are logged as incomming from Server1's IP.

Why is this, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

This is why the good people at Squid invented `X-Forwarded-For`.

On your proxying servers, the header should be added to requests already; `mod_proxy` takes care of this.

On the backend server, modify your existing logging configuration to remove the remote host (`%h`) and add the contents of that header (`%{X-Forwarded-For}i`).  For instance:

```
LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common_forwarded
CustomLog logs/access_log common_forwarded
```

Comment: Just remember that X-Forwarded-For can contain multiple IP addresses, so you may find the log has multiple entries (if the client has already had the request proxied somewhere en route for example).

Comment: @EightBitTony Yup, thanks for mentioning that.  If that's a problem (breaking a log parsing tool, for instance), it's nothing that `RequestHeader unset X-Forwarded-For` can't fix, dropping the data sent by the en route proxy.